# Android Studio <Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0>

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i can't fix tihs problem **Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0**

anybody can fix this problem?
[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abIbd.png)

buid.gradle

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Your question says 28.0.0. Your screenshot (which should be a pasted text version of the error) says 27.1.1. You also don't have your build.gradle in your question.

Comment: `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`

Comment: post your project `build.grade`

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Comment: build.gradle in my questions

Comment: @reza - Your Question still says com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1. You need to correct it. Use the edit link! (And while you are at it, you could correct the spelling and other errors.)

Comment: Did you sync project with gradle files after changing repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check your build.gradle(Project), whether it was looking like below or not

[image]

Second, check your build.gradle(Module:app), whether it was looking like below or not
[image]

Please let me know, whether your issue has been resolved or not

Comment: **when i change classpath in build.gradle(Project) from 3.2.1 to 3.2.0  show me erorr _Connection timed out: connect_**

Comment: Don't change from current stable version to the old version, it can cause those errors. Did u face any other error cases other than Connection timed out error.

Comment: **My Problem Solved**

Comment: @reza Then please accept my answer as helpful. Your valuable feedback is more helpful for me to provide more answers to problems.